# In MkDocs, how to include script-generated content?

Tags: documentation, mkdocs

How can I include script-generated content into documentation built by mkdocs (or mike)?

For example, I'd like to present a table of the command-line arguments of a program, and currently the most complete listing (and descriptions) for those arguments (as supported by a given version of the program) is the output from the program itself (invoked with the `--help` flag). Similarly as for API documentation, if I was to manually transcribe into a markdown file then there would be a maintenance burden to prevent drift between the docs and codebase. Do I need to pre-orchestrate a script that generates entire markdown files, or is there a way to embed shell commands within the docs source (to be evaluated automatically when the docs are built)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question because it helped me to find a solution !

You can actually use this nice plugin https://pawamoy.github.io/markdown-exec/

like this

````
```bash exec="on" result="ansi" returncode="1" source="tabbed-left" tabs="Source code|Output"
path/to_your_script/super_script.sh -h 
```
````

This basically will call the script when `mkdocs` generate the docs and dump the stdout in the code block.

[image: sample of output]

With the configuration that I gave you, you can see the calling command in another tab. You cal tweak the returncode if it doesn't return 0 and you can use ansi to make it beautiful !